# How to enable KVM on a Mac for Qemu?

Tags: macos, virtualization, qemu, kvm, macos-mojave

I'm virtualizing a machine for the first time on my Mac with Qemu (for an university assignment, so it's not possible to change the tool).
We have to compare some measurements between a VM running on KVM and one without KVM.
I tried to start the KVM machine by calling `qemu-system-x86_64 my.qcow2 -enable-kvm` but I'm getting this error:
`qemu-system-x86_64: -machine accel=kvm: No accelerator found`

I checked `sysctl -a | grep machdep.cpu.features` and that`s my output:

> machdep.cpu.features: FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR
>   PGE MCA CMOV PAT PSE36 CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM PBE
>   SSE3 PCLMULQDQ DTES64 MON DSCPL VMX EST TM2 SSSE3 FMA CX16 TPR PDCM
>   SSE4.1 SSE4.2 x2APIC MOVBE POPCNT AES PCID XSAVE OSXSAVE SEGLIM64
>   TSCTMR AVX1.0 RDRAND F16C

As there is VMX listed I assume my Macbook supports KVM and by default it should be enabled as far as I understood.
So why am I getting this error and does anybody have a solution to that?
Btw. my Macbook Pro is a Retina, 13' Mid 2014 version running 10.14.1 (18B75).

Comment: KVM is a Linux thing. Boot Linux. Or ask your instructor what they meant for you to do.

Comment: you may look into Intel HAXM as an alternative on macOS and Windows.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

kvm is the linux hypervisor implementation, that isn't going to work.
Recent qemu version have support for the macos hypervisor framework, use `accel=hvf` for that.

For example:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2G -hda ubuntu.20.qcow2 -accel hvf
```

Comment: @patreu22 I too want to get KVM on my mac but don't know how to start. Can you please point me the correct direction.

Comment: Hey @Naxi , as pointed out by Gerd KVM doesn't work for Mac, the solution is to go with Qemu and accelerate it via hvf. Here is a guide how to do this: https://graspingtech.com/ubuntu-desktop-18.04-virtual-machine-macos-qemu/

Comment: @patreu22 following the guide it showed "The -accel and "-machine accel=" options are incompatible". Removing "-accel hvf" it showed "invalid accelerator kvm". It runs only when "-accel hvf" and no "-enable-kvm"

Comment: The answer lacks the detail how to apply the "`accel=hvf`".

Comment: @Nakilon Passing `-accel hvf` on the qemu-system-x86_64 command line worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your command doesn't include  `-enable-kvm or kvm=on in -cpu`

**This worked for me:**

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -vga virtio -display cocoa,show-cursor=on -usb -device usb-tablet -cdrom ~/VMs/isos/ubuntu-18.10-live-server-amd64.iso -drive file=~/VMs/qemu/ubuntu-server-18.04.qcow2,if=virtio -accel hvf -cpu Penryn,vendor=GenuineIntel
```